# change the tr field in a jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to change a yes to a select dropdown that allow user to select yes or no.

the html is like that:

```
<tr>
<td> text </td>
<td>no(must be changed by js)</td>
<td><a href="#">My button</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> text </td>
<td>yes(must be changed by js)</td>
<td><a href="#">My button</a></td>
</tr>
...
$('a[href="#"]').click(function() {...} });
```

I want to change the content of the "yes" just before the button to a dropdown list **AND** the value of the href of the button clicked to do some treatment in back.

I tried this but it doesn't work after the alert... :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //to make the authority editable
    $('a[href="#"]').click(function() {
        var select = this.parentElement.parentElement;
        alert(select);
        select: nth - child(2).apped("hello");
    });
 </script>
```

Thanks to help me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) traversal methods

```
$('a[href="#"]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().prev().html('xxx')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Zya7S/)

---

If you want to use [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), you need to find the `tr` of the clicked button then use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('a[href="#"]').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find(':nth-child(2)').html('xxx')
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Zya7S/2/)

Comment: Hi @Arun ! Thanks for your answer, it's THE solution :-) In addition, I wanted to change the link, so I just add $(this).attr("href", "http://www.google.com/"); after your .html('xxx') :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two `tr` in your table like above HTML markup, You can use **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** like this:

```
$('a[href="#"]').click(function() {
    var select = this.parentElement.parentElement;
    alert(select);
    $('tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)').append("hello");
});
```

Also, you're probably looking for **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** instead of `.append()` to change the text inside your `td`:

```
$('tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)').text("hello");
```

Comment: Hi @Felix . Thanks for your answer. I hadn't said that but The number of tr depends on te data, so I can't use your technique but many thanks!